# SEO-meta description crawling issue

Tags: seo, php

i have following code where i m including my title and description for the page But google crawled only title not the meta description from the code. Where as meta description was read from the keywords present in html of the page.. Please guide me guys where i m coding wrongly

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>title inserted here</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<meta name="description" content="description here"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where as meta description was read from the keywords present in html of the page..

That is how Google works. The description shown in the SERPs is not necessarily your meta description, it can be any part of your page content that Google deems more relevant to what the user is searching for.

Comment: But,how can google read my provided meta description in the page,not keywords from the page

Comment: Google will have crawled your meta description and it is possible that this will appear in the search results, however, Google is also likely to use content from the page if it determines that this is more relevant to the search. Unfortunately there is nothing you can do about this. Google doesn't always get it right either.

Comment: k.But the syntax which i have given above is correct?,ryt

Comment: Yes, the syntax you have given is OK, although the self-closing slash (`/`) is unnecessary. (If this answers your question then you can mark it as accepted by clicking on the tick to the left of the answer.)

Comment: If your title tag and description meta-tag is too short or too long, Google will make one up. Title tags should be no more than 55 characters and more than say about 45 or so. Description meta-tag should be about 150+ characters but no more than 160. If the search term(s) are not found in the description meta tag, then Google will use a snippet from the content. Do not make the mistake that Google does not read or index something. You just may not be seeing it under the search conditions you used.